# how to access $_FILES parameters while trying to do File Upload without Form?

Tags: file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I have written a functionality where I want to upload a form without using any forms whatsoever, I am calling an ajax event on change event of input type=file with id, I am getting the $_FILES data in ajax file 'upload.php' using POST method using jQuery. The input tag is not inside any form tag. It stands individually. Below is my code:

my plain html input type='file' without form:

```
<div class="profile_pic">
 <img id="upload-button" class="profile-pic img-circle profile_img" src="img/default-image.png" alt="default">
 <input class="file-upload" type="file" name="profile_pic" id="profile_pic" />
</div>
```

My Javascript code is:

```
  var readURL = function(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#upload-button').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
 $(".file-upload").on('change', function(){
        readURL(this);

        alert('working');
            var file = profile_pic.files[0];
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('formData', file);

            $.ajax({
                url: "uploadFile.php",    
                type: "POST",
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                dataType : 'json',
                data: formData,
                success: function (data) {
                  alert(data);
                  }
            });
    });
    $("#upload-button").on('click', function() {
       $(".file-upload").click();
    });
```

UploadFile.php code below:

```
<?php
 print_r($_FILES);
 ?>
```

the following file data Am getting in alert :

```
Array
(

 [formData] => Array
 (
   [name]=> Tulips.jpg
   [type]=> image/jpeg
   [tmp_name]=> chroot/tmp/phpipdF97
   [error]=> 0
   [size]=> 620888
 )

)
```

how can I access those file data inorder to upload file to a destination folder path using php's move_uploaded_file()? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. I have accessed the $_FILES values in "uploadFile.php" like below:

```
$_FILES["formData"]["tmp_name"]
$_FILES["formData"]["name"]
```